# My router's name is "gateway". Where is this set and may I change it?

Tags: networking, 16.04

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 I found that my router has somehow gained an additional name, "gateway". I can run `ping gateway` and it works, which is neat. `ping routers_original_name` also still works.

But syslog-ng now shows this "gateway" name in its remote logs.
And generally, I would like to understand where this name comes from.

It's not in `/etc/hosts`, and `sudo grep -r gateway /etc/` didn't find anything related. My router's DNS server also doesn't know that name. A Google search for anything I could think of also wasn't useful.

The resolver somehow knows this name "gateway":

```
# ping gateway
PING gateway (192.168.7.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from gateway (192.168.7.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.315 ms
^C
--- gateway ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.315/0.317/0.320/0.018 ms

# traceroute gateway
traceroute to gateway (192.168.7.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (192.168.7.1)  0.348 ms  0.449 ms  0.586 ms

# resolveip gateway
IP address of gateway is 192.168.7.1

# resolveip 192.168.7.1
Host name of 192.168.7.1 is gateway
```

Tools using the DNS like `dig -x` or `nslookup` don't know about this name:

```
# nslookup gateway
Server:         192.168.7.1
Address:        192.168.7.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find gateway: No answer
```

Apparently `systemd-resolved` might be "the culprit". From its man page:

> systemd-resolved synthesizes DNS RRs for the following cases:
>   ...
>   The hostname "gateway" is resolved to all current default routing gateway
>   addresses, ordered by their metric. This assigns a stable hostname to
>   the current gateway, useful for referencing it independently of the
>   current network configuration state.

But after a fresh boot, it is not started (and `ping gateway` still works):

```
% systemctl status systemd-resolved.service 
* systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
% journalctl -u systemd-resolved        
-- No entries --
```

Comment: What brand/model of router do you have? Do you know the admin password? Do you have a separate firewall box? Are you on a cable modem, dsl modem, etc? In terminal, type ifconfig, and post the results here.

Comment: My DSL router is a Fritzbox with Freetz, running dnsmasq. But DNS is not involved. `ifconfig` won't help, because it doesn't show anything about host names.

Answer (score 2):

`gateway` is the default name aliased to the IP address through which outgoing network traffic must be directed.  It is default alias, though it can be altered via `/etc/hosts` file .

This is not a hostname asigned via `dns` , hence tools like `dig` and `nslookup` won't find it.

It is also displayed with `route` command. The `route` command only reads data from `/proc/net/route` (which is supplied by the kernel)

```
$ LC_ALL=C route | head -n3                                                                                              
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway       0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan7
```

One can set additional alias via `/etc/hosts` file , as in the example below:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts | head -n 3                                                                                             
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   eagle
192.168.0.1     MY_ROUTER
$ LC_ALL=C route | head -n 3
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         MY_ROUTER       0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan7
$ ping -c 1 MY_ROUTER
PING MY_ROUTER (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from MY_ROUTER (192.168.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=1.58 ms

--- MY_ROUTER ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.586/1.586/1.586/0.000 ms
```

From what I have researched online, appears `gateway` alias is set at kernel level to whatever router address is returned from `dhcp` server. 
It will still respond to pings even after being edited in `/etc/hosts`

```
$ ping -c 1 gateway 
PING gateway (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from MY_ROUTER (192.168.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=1.90 ms

--- gateway ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.905/1.905/1.905/0.000 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

its not renamed to gateway... 
http://whatismyipaddress.com/gateway

And if you want to change your wifi name do ifconfig
and find default route it should look like 192.168.1.1 or something along those lines.

Comment: You missed that I mentioned that I can run `ping gateway` and it works. Additionally, `traceroute gateway` also works. And my wifi SSID is totally unrelated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, because it showed that my question wasn't clear enough. I added the output of some commands so it is easier to see why I'm baffled.