# What is _gateway in my route table?

Tags: networking, router

I just ran "route" on my laptop's terminal and see this line for the default entry in my route table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XpYk.png)

In examples I am seeing in books and online, the default entry includes an actual ip address for the gateway. Why do I not have that and have "_gateway" instead? What does "_gateway" mean? Is it possible to retrieve the actual ip address of the gateway?

Comment: Are you actually connected to a network? What does `host _gateway;ip addr` show? It looks like a placeholder for an unconnected system. Please copy/paste and format text instead of pictures of text. A picture (of text) can't be read on a text-only terminal, can't be copied from (edited, tried, and made to work), AND makes one take an action to even read your Question. Since we're all volunteers, some won't click. Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Only showing the 1 line is not enough info.  Please use copy and paste from the terminal into your question.  It does look like though that the `_gateway` is just the name of the gateway device (router).

Answer (score 2):

Just here to remind you and others who may have the same question...
There is a similar question in StackExchange which is already solved:[My router's name is "gateway". Where is this set and may I change it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806778/my-routers-name-is-gateway-where-is-this-set-and-may-i-change-it)

Note that your "_gateway" and "gateway" in this question is actually the same thing. Refer to this for a validation: [Why does Ubuntu resolve the name `_gateway` to the default gateway instead of `gateway`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546736/why-does-ubuntu-resolve-the-name-gateway-to-the-default-gateway-instead-of-g)